# Symfony2: Order form fields

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.5

Consider this piece of code:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('description', 'textarea')
        ->add('status', 'choice', array('choices' => array('online' => 'online', 'offline' => 'offline')))
        ->add('save', 'submit');
}
```

But when I render this form I get it in the order

```
description
name
status
```

How can I change this besides writing the form template by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hoping to control the render order from your PHP, but in reality, your PHP ought not know about, nor care about, how information is rendered. The order of rendering is handled in the template, preferably via twig, as it is the template's responsibility to handle this. It is a straightforward process, and gives you plenty of control. The following Twig template ought to fix your order:

```
{{form_start(nameOfFormVariablePassedFromController}}
    {{form_label(nameOfFormVariablePassedFromController.name)}}
    {{form_widget(nameOfFormVariablePassedFromController.name)}}

    {{form_label(nameOfFormVariablePassedFromController.description)}}
    {{form_widget(nameOfFormVariablePassedFromController.description)}}

    {{form_label(nameOfFormVariablePassedFromController.status)}}
    {{form_widget(nameOfFormVariablePassedFromController.status)}}

    {{form_widget(nameOfFormVariablePassedFromController.save)}}
{{form_end(nameOfFormVariablePassedFromController}}
```

It is easy to add classes to these labels and widgets for styling, by adding extra arguments. I can help with this if you need further clarification.

Comment: I already thought so. Strictly you're right, but still it feels a bit strange.

Comment: It can seem a little long winded to begin with, but separating the presentation from the logic is a widely regarded best practice, enabling easy modifications to one, without affecting the other, so you're better to embrace it.

Answer (score 4):

Had same issue today with the form elements ordering.

Ended up with a trait that will override finishView method and reorder items in children property of a FormView:

```
trait OrderedTrait
{
    abstract function getFieldsOrder();

    public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        /** @var FormView[] $fields */
        $fields = [];
        foreach ($this->getFieldsOrder() as $field) {
            if ($view->offsetExists($field)) {
                $fields[$field] = $view->offsetGet($field);
                $view->offsetUnset($field);
            }
        }

        $view->children = $fields + $view->children;

        parent::finishView($view, $form, $options);
    }
}
```

Then in type implement getFieldsOrder method:

```
use OrderedTrait;

function getFieldsOrder()
{
    return [
        'first',
        'second',
        'next',
        'etc.',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://github.com/egeloen/ivory-ordered-form/ bundle. Maybe someday it will be integrated into core. For now, symfony Form component doesn't have any order option.